# P2P Flash game #1009 error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder, p2p

I am trying to create a very basic flash game, using Tom Krcha's P2P gaming library, which I found [here](http://www.flashrealtime.com/p2p-game-lib/), the only problem I have is when I try to implement the class, I get a error when I try to launch the app,

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Logger$/log()[C:\_DEV\P2PGameEngine\src\Logger.as:20]
    at P2PGame/onConnect()[C:\_DEV\P2PGameEngine\src\P2PGame.as:54]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at com.adobe.fms::P2PSession/onNetGroupConnect()[C:\_DEV\P2PMessengerLib\src\com\adobe\fms\P2PSession.as:208]
    at com.adobe.fms::P2PSession/netStatus()[C:\_DEV\P2PMessengerLib\src\com\adobe\fms\P2PSession.as:312]
```

here is my Flash Builder code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       width="520" height="391"
                       applicationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var game:P2PGame;

            private const SERVER:String = "rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net/";
            private const DEVKEY:String = "DEV_KEY_HERE";

            protected function init():void
            {

                var usr:String = "user"+(Math.round(Math.random()*1000));

                game = new P2PGame(SERVER+DEVKEY,"my_group");
                game.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onGameConnect);
                game.connect(usr);

            }

            private function onGameConnect(event:Event):void{

                main_log.text += "P2P connection successfull..."

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:TextArea id="main_users" x="346" y="10" width="164" height="371" color="#FFFFFF"
                contentBackgroundColor="#000000" text="ACTIVE USERS" textAlign="center"
                textDecoration="underline" verticalAlign="top"/>
    <s:TextArea id="main_log" x="10" y="10" width="328" height="371"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

any idea why this could be happening? I have included the libraries, and yet I still get that error, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is thrown in the log() function of the [Logger class](https://github.com/tomkrcha/RealtimeGameLib/blob/master/src/realtimelib/Logger.as).

There is nothing else but a TextField, whose properties are being accessed, so this is probably the culprit (`txtArea` is `null` at some point).  Strangely enough, there is an if statement in the source code, which should prevent this kind of error (`if (txtArea != null)`).  Could you be working with an older version?  You should probably download the source code from github and see if the current version still throws the same error.

**EDIT**

I just created a little test with the SWC package:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        public function Test ()
        {
            Logger.log ("something");
        }
    }
}
```

Run it, and voilà:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Logger$/log()
    at Test()

Whereas with the source version from github, everything runs fine (though doesn't do anything).

Comment: I actually just downloaded the latest version of the library just now. So I doubt it could be that...

Comment: Great stuff, seems that is was the `SWC` just as you said, I downloaded and included the library project file again, changed the version to `10.2.0`, then included that into the build path of my project, and it worked! Thanks for the help!